# Why ItemsControl item's DataContext assigned after they've been rendered

Tags: wpf, binding, datatemplate, itemscontrol

I have the following ItemsControl defined in my XAML:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="myDataTemplate">
        <Grid Margin="20">

            <View:MyView Width="123" Height="212"/>

        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyVMs}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myDataTemplate}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

And DataContext of the `View:MyView` gets assigned after all UI elements where rendered. I am interested to know, why is that happening?

Comment: How are you determining that the DataContext is being assigned after the elements are rendered? is this something you can see happening in the UI? or are you handling the DataContextChnaged event?

Comment: I check the DataContext before calling InitializeComponent and in the Loaded evenHandler. In the first case it is null and in the loaded event handler it got assigned to the right VM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DataContext is not set after the elements are rendered. If this was the case, you would see the your elements rendered twice, once initially when the DataContext is null, and the second time when the DataContext is set and your bindings are evaluated.

From what you are describing, you are breakpointing or tracing within the constructor. Properties cannot be set on a class before they are constructed!

Comment: Right! So that means that constructor will Initialise all Dependency Properties of the control?

Comment: Not exactly - it is the responsibility of the ItemsControl to set the DataContext for each of the elements it creates.